# Sonar upgrade to Community Version 5.6 Failed

Tags: database, sonarqube, upgrade

The version upgrade was almost over and the error that I get is below:

```
web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] Starting DB Migration
2016.09.03 20:59:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  DropTableGraphs: migrating ================================================
2016.09.03 20:59:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- remove_index("graphs", {:name=>"graphs_perspectives"})
2016.09.03 20:59:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=2879ms
2016.09.03 20:59:14 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has
occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Table 'sonar.graphs' doesn't exist
```

I am in the middle of the migration and have no clue about what has to be done further.
I would appreciate any help that I could get!

Comment: I hope you have a backup to start again. What is the starting SonarQube version? Did you update the plugins first? Maybe it helps if you remove the SonarGraph plugin before update and install the plugin after the upgrade.

Comment: Replaced quote tags with code tags to properly align and format display of error